# Azure Sendgrid has gone missing

Tags: azure, azure-functions, sendgrid

as the title states... The sendgrid in my Azure portal is missing and I did not get any notifications about this. Does anyone know what happened? I searched for the resource and it's not there but recommends me to get a sendgrid twilio.

The weird part is my function apps are still linked into the sendgrid and I have no access to it. I also have a sendgrid function url...

Any ideas what is going on?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I finally found mine in the Azure Portal. They have been renamed from SendGrid to SaaS

[image]

Comment: Why this is not the the most voted answer here? I wrote Saas in my azure portal and found it thanks to @Ryan Durkin

Answer (score 1):

As per this [Document](https://www.twilio.com/press/releases/twilio-completes-acquisition-sendgrid) `Twilio` has completely acquired `sendgrid` and that is one of the reason why you are unable to find `sendgrid` in azure portal rather you can able to find Twilio `sendgrid`.

So what ever you want to create you need to do it only through `Twilio Sendgrid`

[image]

[image]

As per the statement from the above image what ever you want to deal with Sendgrid you can check in Twilio Send grid

Here is the [document](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/partners/microsoft-azure-2021#create-a-twilio-sendgrid-account) for creating Twilio Sendgrid Email API.

Comment: Okay, but this doesn't answer where my current sendgrid account is located or how to find the details to login. It is still hooked into my functions...

Comment: As the Sendgrid is a Partner to Microsoft for any technical related quarries you can use dedicated [Sendgrid Forum](https://support.sendgrid.com/hc/en-us) where you will be getting solutions from expertise

Comment: Twilio developer evangelist here. I also recommend that you get in touch with SendGrid support to find out what has happened in your Azure account. Things shouldn't just disappear.

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as an answer( click on the checkmark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to fill in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you